# Video and image upload to rails server

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms

My view is rendering a form that has input fields added via controls on the client side.

E.g:

1. Form starts out empty
2. user clicks on add an module
3. inputs are inserted via jquery (select/text/file)
4. user clicks on another module
5. more inputs

With multiple modules in my form, I want to organize the input for my rails server. I do so by looping through all the input fields, creating a json hash and sending it in a single form/input section via .submit(). Something like this:

{ module_1: 
  { field_1: value
    field_2: value
    field_3: value
  }
}

Now I'm focusing on allowing users to add files like video and images, but that won't work with my Json. Another option is to use a POST, and submitting the request via AJAX, but I need a new view to be rendered from the inputs.

I wondering if there is a way send the file in a hash structure, and send it over to the server without the use of AJAX?

Answer (score 0):

You would not add binary data like a video in JSON data. However you would pass the video as a url to the client-side. Like this:

```
{ "videos": 
   [
     { "video_name": "Test Video","video_url": "http://.../video.mpeg" }
   ]
}
```